# Update query from multiple tables, for specific IDs and JOIN LIMIT 1

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, and I want to update the rows of `torrents` from `scrapes` every day.

**scrapes:**

```
id, torrent_id, name, status, complete, incomplete, downloaded
1, 1, http://tracker1.com, 1, 542, 23, 542
2, 1, http://tracker2.com, 1, 542, 23, 542
3, 2, http://tracker1.com, 1, 123, 34, 43
4, 2, http://tracker2.com, 1, 123, 34, 43
5, 3, http://tracker1.com, 1, 542, 23, 542
6, 3, http://tracker2.com, 1, 542, 23, 542
7, 4, http://tracker1.com, 1, 123, 34, 43
8, 4, http://tracker2.com, 1, 123, 34, 43
9, 5, http://tracker1.com, 1, 542, 23, 542
10, 5, http://tracker2.com, 1, 542, 23, 542
11, 6, http://tracker1.com, 1, 123, 34, 43
12, 6, http://tracker2.com, 1, 123, 34, 43
```

**torrents:**

```
id, name, complete, incomplete, downloaded
1, CentOS, 0, 0, 0
2, Ubuntu, 0, 0, 0
3, Debian, 0, 0, 0
4, Redhat, 0, 0, 0
5, Fedora, 0, 0, 0
6, Gentoo, 0, 0, 0
```

The `scrapes` may have multiple `name`, but I want to get the values only from the first found (for better performance) and also, I need to update only `torrents` ids `1, 3, 6` on one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE (SELECT * FROM scrapes WHERE torrent_id IN(1,3,6) GROUP BY torrent_id) as `myview` JOIN torrents ON myview.torrent_id=torrents.id SET torrent.complete=myview.complete WHERE 1
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the `WHERE 1` for? Nevermind, I've just saw on the web :-)

Comment: Where 1 just to see complete query structure as I donot have any condition to apply